# finding preceding-sibling and processing in same node

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Need to transform following XML snippet into DITA using XSLT. My requirements are: 
1. All the tags comes before "orderedlist" should be wrapped under "context" node. 
2. All the tags comes after "orderedlist" should be in "result".
3. All the "include" tags should be wrapped under their preceding sibling nodes.

XML:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <procedure>
            <para>This is first para</para>
            <para>This is second para</para>
            <include>This is include</include>
            <orderedlist>
                <listitem>this is list item</listitem>
                <include>This is include</include>
                <listitem>this is list item <include>this is include</include></listitem>
            </orderedlist>
            <observation>this is observation</observation>
            <para>this is result para <include>this is include</include></para>
            <include>This is include</include>
        </procedure>
```

Output:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <task>
        <context>
            <p>This is first para</p>
            <p>This is second para <included type='tag'>This is include</included>
            </p>
        </context>
        <ol>
            <li>this is list item <included type='tag'>This is include</included>
            </li>
            <li>this is list item <included type='tag'>this is include</included></li>
        </ol>
        <result>
            <observation>this is observation</observation>
            <p>this is result para <included type='tag'>this is include</included><included type='tag'>this is include</included>
            </p>
        </result>
    </task>
```

My XSL:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
            <xsl:template match="procedure">
                <task>
                    <context>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[parent::procedure][following-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
                    </context>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="orderedlist"/>
                    <result>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[parent::procedure][preceding-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
                    </result>
                </task>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="para">
                <p>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <include>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::include"/>
                    </include>
                </p>
            </xsl:template>
            <!-- rest of the template goes here   -->
            <xsl:template match="listitem">
                <li>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    <include>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::include"/>
                    </include>
                </li>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any pointer will be a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is you can simplify the following expression:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[parent::procedure][following-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
```

You don't need the `[parent::procedure]` here, because you are already positioned on a **procedure** element, so so you know if you select any child element, it will have that as a parent!

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[following-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
```

However, you might need to add an clause to ensure you don't output the **include** elements at this point, as you will need special code to handle them being included later

```
<xsl:template match="include" />
```

To handle the **include** elements, it might be worth defining a key, so you can group them by the first most proceding non-include element, like so

```
  <xsl:key name="include" match="include" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::include)][1])"/>
```

Then, when matching an element such as **para** or **listitem**, you can then get the **include** elements to include, just like this:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="key('include', generate-id())"/>
```

Note I am not sure how you want to handle multipe **include** elements for a single element, but in my example, it will output them separately as opposing to merging them:

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="include" match="include" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::include)][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="procedure">
    <task>
      <context>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[following-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
      </context>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="orderedlist"/>
      <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[preceding-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
      </result>
    </task>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="orderedlist">
    <ol>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ol>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('include', generate-id())" />
     </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="listitem">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('include', generate-id())" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<task>
  <context>
    <p>This is first para</p>
    <p>This is second para<include>This is include</include></p>
  </context>
  <ol>
    <li>this is list item<include>This is include</include></li>
    <li>this is list item</li>
  </ol>
  <result>
    <observation>this is observation</observation>
    <p>this is result para<include>This is include</include></p>
  </result>
</task>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the details explanation. This solution works perfectly fine unless i encounter: 1. 'inlcude' tags can appear anywhere in xml, where i have to process it as it is(the preceding-sibling logic should not be applicable for those 'include'). 2. I may have to manipulate 'include' tag hence, i have to do apply-template instead of copy-of. Any suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="Copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      <xsl:call-template name="Include" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="procedure">
    <task>
      <context>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[following-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
      </context>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="orderedlist"/>
      <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[preceding-sibling::orderedlist]"/>
      </result>
    </task>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:call-template name="Include" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- rest of the template goes here   -->
  <xsl:template match="listitem">
    <li>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <xsl:call-template name="Include" />
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Include">
    <xsl:apply-templates
      select="following-sibling::include[
                       generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::include)][1]) =
                       generate-id(current())]"
      mode="performIncludes"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="include" />
  <xsl:template match="include" mode="performIncludes">
    <xsl:call-template name="Copy" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output when run on your sample input:

```
<task>
  <context>
    <p>This is first para</p>
    <p>This is second para<include>This is include</include></p>
  </context>
  <orderedlist>
    <li>this is list item<include>This is include</include></li>
    <li>this is list item</li>
  </orderedlist>
  <result>
    <observation>this is observation</observation>
    <p>this is result para<include>This is include</include></p>
  </result>
</task>
```